# Save a shapefile with the original name as the imported file in R

Tags: shapefile, r, save

I want to save as shapefile an object but I want the name of the shp to be the same (original) as the file I imported at the beginning of my code. I don't want to do it manually because at a later stage I will import hundreds of texts and I will want to save them as `shp` with their original names. Here is my code:

```
setwd("mydir") 
d = read.table("vourlionas.txt",
               header = FALSE,
               sep="", 
               col.names=c("x", "y"), 
               fill=FALSE, 
               strip.white=TRUE,
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

some data manipulation here

writeOGR(obj=test1, dsn="mydir", layer = "ORIGINALFILENAME"
               driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE)
```

I believe it has to do something with `layer` parameter. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be as easy as:

```
filename="vourlionas"
setwd("mydir") 
d = read.table(paste(filename,"txt",sep="."),
           header = FALSE,
           sep="", 
           col.names=c("x", "y"), 
           fill=FALSE, 
           strip.white=TRUE,
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 some data manipulation here

 writeOGR(obj=test1, dsn="mydir", layer = filename,
           driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE)
```

If you get your original filenames by eg reading the contents of a directory, you need to start with

```
 txtfilename="vourlionas.txt"
 filename=strsplit(txtfilename, "\\.")[[1]]
```